# Reduce onIncrement() and onDecrement() to 1 function Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am coding a counters app. So I want to replace onIncrement, onDecrement function by onChange function.

I want to remove onIncrement and onDecrement function. Then I want to add new onChange function

The onChange function should take a single parameter and it can decrement or increment a counter.

my code:

```
const Counter = props => {
  const { onIncrement, onDecrement, count, index } = props;

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <b>{count}</b>
      <div className="counter-controls">
        <button
          onClick={() => onDecrement(index)}
          className="button is-danger is-small"
        >
          -
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => onIncrement(index)}
          className="button is-success is-small"
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Total = props => {
  const { sum } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Total: {sum} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 }
  ]);

  const total = data.map(item => item.value).reduce((p, n) => p + n);

  const [sum, setSum] = useState(total);

  const handleIncrement = index => {
    const clone = [...data];
    clone[index - 1].value += 1;
    setData(clone);
    setSum(sum + 1);
  };
  const handleDecrement = index => {
    const clone = [...data];
    clone[index - 1].value -= 1;
    setData(clone);
    setSum(sum - 1);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(counter => (
        <Counter
          key={counter.id}
          onIncrement={handleIncrement}
          onDecrement={handleDecrement}
          index={counter.id}
          count={counter.value}
        />
      ))}
      <Total sum={sum} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single onChange function and pass on the change value while calling the function. Use the changeValue to add to the previous data. For a decrement implementation change value will be `-1` and for `increment` it will be `+1`

```
const Counter = props => {
  const { onChange, count, index } = props;

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <b>{count}</b>
      <div className="counter-controls">
        <button
          onClick={() => onChange(index, -1)}
          className="button is-danger is-small"
        >
          -
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => onChange(index, 1)}
          className="button is-success is-small"
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Total = props => {
  const { sum } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Total: {sum} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 }
  ]);

  const total = data.map(item => item.value).reduce((p, n) => p + n);

  const [sum, setSum] = useState(total);

  const handleChange = (index, changeValue) => {
    const clone = [...data];
    clone[index - 1].value += changeValue;
    setData(clone);
    setSum(prevSum = prevSum + changeValue);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(counter => (
        <Counter
          key={counter.id}
          onChange={handleChange}
          index={counter.id}
          count={counter.value}
        />
      ))}
      <Total sum={sum} />
    </div>
  );
}
```